# Integrate Ren'Py into GameMaker(by YoYogames)

Tags: game-engine, game-maker

As the title already mentioned I want to know how to integrate the Ren'Py engine into GameMaker by YoYogames. I'm in a competition where you have to make your own game in the GameMaker programme but I want to use the digital storytelling from Ren'Py.
Anyone an idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Wouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap Ren'Py inside a dll (with C-function for gamemaker to call). Though also remember GM is limited in what extensions can do (basically either take over the complete drawing of the game or leave the drawing to GM and use your dll to pass strings/numbers only).

Though once you start doing this the question becomes "why use gm" - and " can you really call this a game made with gamemaker".